# jQuery $.ajax() call introducing XSS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xss

Today I noticed when I go to my site it shows an `alert(1);` and redirects anyone that goes to it so some other site.

I knew it was a JavaScript exploit so I took out bits of code at a time and came to find that the below bit of code is what is causing the vulnerability.

```
var all_chats = setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: './requests/chat.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(chats) {
      $('.chat').html(chats);
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

The chat.php file is this:

```
<?php 
  require '../includes/functions.php';   
?>

<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' class='resultsTable'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>NAME</td>
            <td>TIME</td>
            <td>CONVERSATION</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php echo getChats(); ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

PHP getChats() function:

```
function getChats() {

global $PDO;

    $stm = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM `chats` ORDER BY `cid` DESC LIMIT 100");

        $stm->execute();

            while($Try = $stm->fetchAll()) {
                foreach($Try as $Array) {
                            if(!isset($row_num)) $row_num = 1;
                            $row_class = (++$row_num % 2) ? '' : 'greyRow';

                                echo '<tr class="' . $row_class . '">';
                                echo '<td>' . $Array['uid'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>' . time_ago(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $Array['time'])) . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>' . $Array['message'] . '</td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                }
            }

}
```

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: The vulnerability isn't in the posted code since you aren't sending any data to the server...

Comment: What does `getChats` return? Escape that. Or better, don't return that whole HTML with AJAX - return just the data and use `.text` instead of `.html`

Comment: The question is how could this code cause that error?

Comment: Added the PHP function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is vulnerable to XSS if you allow users to store their inputs as chats in database ***without encoding***.
So when you call this to return what is stored as it is

```
<?php echo getChats(); ?>
```

The string is returned to the client which may contain malicious input and this code will execute it:

```
$('.chat').html(chats);
```

Comment: Exactly, in the OP's case `htmlspecialchars` would do the trick.